# What does "僕はもう君以外何もいらない君だけが欲しいんだ。金はもうあるし” mean?

Tags: jokes

This picture was sent to a friend  by a woman he was talking to

[image: 僕はもう君以外何もいらない君だけが欲しいんだ。金はもうあるし]

We think we get what the literal meaning is but have no idea about the nuance of what it actually means.

For example, it could mean exactly what it we think it says. Effectively something like

> I don't need anything but you. I only want you. You even have money.

But it could also have a cultural background or something such as it could be a put down as in.

> You're actually not my type but you've got money so I'll pretend.

It could also be a famous line or a famous character for all I know

I asked a Japanese female friend, all she told me was "haha", that's funny, and, "I'd never send a message like that to someone I actually liked"

Does anyone know what this is really means?

Comment: My attempt: I don't need anything but you. I only want you. After all, I already have money... (implying the other person is poor).

Comment: Why would that be funny then? (my Japanese friend's reaction). That sounds like something you'd use to effectively say "I like you and I don't need your money". But that's not funny

Comment: It's one of a series of comedic one-frame cartoons, titled 女に惚れさす名言集("A Collection of Brilliant Quotes for Making Chicks Fall for You"), by 地獄のミサワ, published on his blog. His works are characterized by a wry and bizarre sense of humor (to say nothing of the art style). Each of the series' cartoon consists of one of its recurring characters behaving/speaking in a way that is typical of them.

Comment: Here we have the salary-man looking TAKASHI, whose type is that of "a guy who can't get over how rich he is and have to keep reminding his girlfriend of that fact, even while he's telling her how important she is to him." (All the pieces featuring him: http://jigokuno.com/cid_100.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation of the third line is wrong.

> 僕はもう君以外何もいらない。
>     I don't need anything but you.
>
> 君だけが欲しいんだ。
>     I only want you.
>
> 金はもうあるし。
>     (Because) I've already gotten (enough) money. / There is already money.

Well, that's all what these lines say. No puns, no wordplay.

To interpret this as a joke, yes you need to understand the cultural background. This art style is typical 地獄のミサワ's style, and he is famous for this kind of satirical pictures of overly-confident, snobbish people who love sarcasm and showing off their ability (often referred to as [意識高い系](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/40934/5010)). [Some of his works are found here](http://jigokuno.com/). Well, they are surrealistic, and I admit I have difficulty understanding all of them. But I can feel many of them are really ウザい ("annoying"). You can safely assume whatever drawn in this style is a joke.

So 金はもうあるし is the funny (or, "annoying") part of this picture: the guy who seemed earnest at first suddenly started to (indirectly) boast about how rich he is, and he doesn't even know that's a bad way to attract a girl in a romantic situation. This line also ends up implying "you" are not as important as money.